# Galaxy S2 synced but no emails show

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, exchange, active-sync

I have created an exchange account on a Galaxy S2.  Upon creation of the account no errors were thrown or encountered.  Yet when the user open email for this account "refreshing" keeps popping up and going away at the bottom.  No emails ever show up for any folders, but all folders in the exchange account do appear.  When the user sends an email via the GS2 two identical emails are sent.  The exchange server that the account is on has a ssl certificate from a CA installed and working. Other android/apple phones are working fine.  Several different exchange user accounts have been tested on the GS2 even one created just for testing(one email was sent to this account for testing).  I'm perplexed and need a push in the right direction on what to look for to resolve this issue.  Using a different email app shouldn't be necessary and is not an acceptable answer.  The GS2 is Android's flagship phone and it's email client should be sufficient.  I appreciate any help on the matter.

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: ?Not an answer, but did you resolve it. I have Exchange 2003 and that works well on the phone - but other Exchange 2007 and Office 365 accounts show similar results to what you were experiencing

Answer (score 1):

Exchange server/ domain administrator needs to make a change to your Active directory account by opening ADUC, selecting View, Advanced Features, double clicking your account's property, and going to Security.

From there select Exchange Servers and click on the advanced button.  check the Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent and click ok a couple of times.  After that, the phone should start syncing.